# Unable to run python script during Jenkins build

Tags: python, jenkins

**The problem:**
I have a Jenkins build step that executes a shell script. This script in turn calls a python script which is performing some cryptographic functions. However when the build executes, I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xyz.py", line 4, in <module>
    import rsa
ImportError: No module named 'rsa'
```

The Jenkins' node has two versions of python - 2.7 (default) and 3.4 and `rsa` is installed for both of them. I even ran the script (using version 3.4) on the slave itself and it worked fine.

**What I have done so far:**
I am using EnvInject plugin to point `PYTHONPATH` to correct location. Without it, I found that `PYTHONPATH` was undefined.

- With Python 2.7

Using default version, my script starts with: `#!/usr/bin/env python`
Jenkins output:

```
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[demo] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson9217742060700174209.sh
+ export PYTHONPATH=/jenkins/workspace/demo:/usr/local/lib/python2.7
+ echo /jenkins/workspace/demo:/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/jenkins/workspace/demo:/usr/local/lib/python2.7
+ ./abc.sh
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory
```

- With Python 3.4

The Shebang in this case is `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
Jenkins output:

```
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.4/

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[demo] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4592372533933414288.sh
+ export PYTHONPATH=/jenkins/workspace/demo:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/
+ echo /jenkins/workspace/demo:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/
/jenkins/workspace/demo:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/
+ ./abc.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xyz.py", line 4, in <module>
    import rsa
ImportError: No module named 'rsa'
```

I even tried doing `sys.path.append(os.environ['/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rsa'])` in the script itself, but the problem persists.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks.

P.S.- My knowledge of Python is very limited.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember it, I had similar problems with my Python-script and I finally solved it by using

```
python xyz.py
```

instead of

```
./xyz.py
```

Unfortunately I can not explain why it works in this way, but not the other, but in my case it solved the problem.

Comment: This did not work for me. When I tried, I got `./abc.sh: line 27: python: command not found`. I even accessed the slave node's script console and ran `println "which python".execute().text` which printed `/usr/bin/python` correctly.